# Ghidra headless + bindiff (binexport)

Tags: ghidra, bin-diffing, tool-bindiff

I am working on patch diffing using ghidra + bindiff (specifically, [binexport](https://github.com/google/binexport/tree/main/java/BinExport)), and am looking for advice on using bindiff with Ghidra headless.

[ida_haru](https://github.com/TakahiroHaruyama/ida_haru/blob/master/bindiff/bindiff.py) does essentially everything that I need, but for IDA instead of Ghidra. Specifically, I am wondering if something like the `_make_BinExport()` function exists for Ghidra.

```
def _make_BinExport(self, target, ida_path):
        binexp_path = self._get_db_path_noext(target) + '.BinExport'
        #binexp_path = os.path.splitext(target)[0] + '.BinExport'
        if not self._clear and os.path.exists(binexp_path):
            self._dprint('already existed BinExport: {}'.format(binexp_path))
            return 0

        #cmd = [ida_path, '-A', '-S{}'.format(g_exp_path), '-OExporterModule:{}'.format(binexp_path), target]  # the .BinExport filename should be specified in 4.3
        cmd = [ida_path, '-A', '-S{}'.format(g_exp_path), '-OBinExportModule:{}'.format(binexp_path), target]
        #print cmd
        
        self._dprint('getting BinExport for {}'.format(target))
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        return proc.returncode
```

Things I have done:

1. ghidra headless script to get the `func_names` and `min_addr` for each function in the binaries,
2. python script to work with the `original_vs_patched.BinDiff` files (sqlite3), and correlate results with the `func_names`

I'm missing:

0. ghidra headless script to create and export the `*.BinExport` files

Advice and insights appreciated!

Comment: did you check this project? https://github.com/ubfx/BinDiffHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted my solution GitHub https://github.com/Kayla0x41/ghidraheadless_binexport

The key is the following lines of code (to be used with Ghidra headless):

```
addr_set = currentProgram.getMemory()
f = File(program_name + '.BinExport')
exporter = BinExportExporter() #Binary BinExport (v2) for BinDiff
exporter.export(f, currentProgram, addr_set, monitor)
```

This line is used to export a `sample_name.BinExport` file for each sample analyzed, where `sample_name` is the name of the sample.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/BiSECT-Temp/ghidraheadless_binexport

Answer (score 0):

There are some additional imports required:

```
from com.google.security import binexport
import java.io.File as File
```

without which the codes will not work.